# Add custom option with price

Tags: cart, custom-options

I would like to add a custom option dynamically to a quote item and give it a price.

For example, a checkbox on the cart page that when ticked will add some extra options for the customer and add $5 more to the price of that item.

I am trying to use the product load after event and set the custom option there.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: What magento version do you use?

Comment: community edition 1.9